# Hadoop: strange NullPointer Exception running in local mode

Tags: java, hadoop

I just started to study Hadoop and I have extracted an example from a book. So I have created a MapReducer to run locally that extracts temperatures from NCDC free data files. This is a sample of data:

```
0143023780999992012010100004+61450+017167FM-12+002799999V0209999C...cut...;
```

Every single file (I downloaded around 100 files) is composed by many lines like that.

My mapper executes simple parsing operations to extract temperature from these files. The whole process will return the max temperature.

Mapper and relative tests:

```
public class MaxTemperatureMapper extends Mapper<LongWritable,Text,Text,IntWritable> {

@Override
public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context) {
    String record = value.toString();
    String year = record.substring(15,19);
    int airTemperature = extractTemp(record);
    if (isNotValidTemp(record, airTemperature)) return;
    try {
        context.write(new Text(year), new IntWritable(airTemperature));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private boolean isNotValidTemp(String record, int airTemperature) {
    return airTemperature == 9999 || !record.substring(92, 93).matches("[01459]");
}

private int extractTemp(String record) {
    String temp = (record.charAt(87) == '+')
            ? record.substring(88,92)
            : record.substring(87,92);
    return Integer.parseInt(temp);
}

}

public class MaxTemperatureMapperTest {

@Test
public void processRecord() {
    Text value = new Text("0111011120999992012010100004+65450+012217FM-12+000999999V0201301N014019999999N9999999N1+00031-00791099271ADDMA1999999099171MD1810341+9999REMSYN070AAXX  01001 01112 46/// /1314 10003 21079 39917 49927 58034 333 91124;");

    new MapDriver<LongWritable, Text, Text, IntWritable>()
            .withMapper(new MaxTemperatureMapper())
            .withInputValue(value)
            .withOutput(new Text("2012"), new IntWritable(3))
            .runTest();
}

@Test
public void processRecordsFromSuspiciousFile() throws IOException {
    final InputStream is = getClass().getClassLoader().getSystemResource("023780-99999-2012").openStream();
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
    String line;
    Iterator<Integer> ii = Arrays.asList(-114, -120, -65, -45, 1, 4, 6, 6, 10, 16, 18, 29, 32, 17, 7, 16, 22, 8, 8, 20).iterator();
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        new MapDriver<LongWritable, Text, Text, IntWritable>()
                .withMapper(new MaxTemperatureMapper())
                .withInputValue(new Text(line))
                .withOutput(new Text("2012"), new IntWritable(ii.next()))
                .runTest();
    }
    br.close();


}
}
```

Reducer and relative tests:

```
public class MaxTemperatureReducer extends Reducer<Text,IntWritable,Text,IntWritable> {

@Override
public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<IntWritable> values, Context context) {
    int maxValue = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    for (IntWritable value : values) {
        maxValue = Math.max(value.get(), maxValue);
    }
    try {
        context.write(key, new IntWritable(maxValue));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

}

public class MaxTemperatureReducerTest {

@Test
public void processRecord() {

    new ReduceDriver<Text,IntWritable,Text,IntWritable>()
            .withReducer(new MaxTemperatureReducer())
            .withInputKey(new Text("2012"))
            .withInputValues(Arrays.asList(new IntWritable(5), new IntWritable(10)))
            .withOutput(new Text("2012"), new IntWritable(10))
            .runTest();
}
}
```

Finally the Driver class + test:

```
public class MaxTemperatureDriver extends Configured implements Tool {

@Override
public int run(String[] args) throws Exception {
    if (args.length != 2) {
        System.err.printf("Usage: %s [generic options] <input> <output>\n", getClass().getSimpleName());
        ToolRunner.printGenericCommandUsage(System.err);
        return -1;
    }

    Job job = new Job(getConf(), "Max Temperature");
    job.setJarByClass(getClass());

    FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(args[0]));
    FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[1]));

    job.setMapperClass(MaxTemperatureMapper.class);
    job.setCombinerClass(MaxTemperatureReducer.class);
    job.setReducerClass(MaxTemperatureReducer.class);

    job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
    job.setOutputValueClass(Iterable.class);

    return job.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0 : 1;
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    int exitCode = ToolRunner.run(new MaxTemperatureDriver(), args);
    System.exit(exitCode);
}
}

public class MaxTemperatureDriverTest {

@Test
public void test() throws Exception {
    Configuration conf = new Configuration();
    conf.set("fs.default.name", "file:///");
    conf.set("mapred.job.tracker", "local");

    Path input = new Path("file:////home/user/big-data/ncdc/");
    Path output = new Path("output");

    FileSystem fs = FileSystem.getLocal(conf);
    fs.delete(output, true);

    MaxTemperatureDriver driver = new MaxTemperatureDriver();
    driver.setConf(conf);

    int exitCode = driver.run(new String[] { input.toString(), output.toString() });
    assertThat(exitCode, is(0));
}
}
```

I run the whole process using command line:

```
$> hadoop doop.MaxTemperatureDriver -fs file:/// -jt local ~/big-data/ncdc/ output
```

and the test in MaxTemperatureDriverTest, but in both cases I got:

```
    13/09/21 19:45:13 INFO mapred.MapTask: Processing split: file:/home/user/big-data/ncdc/023780-99999-2012:0+5337
13/09/21 19:45:13 INFO mapred.MapTask: io.sort.mb = 100
13/09/21 19:45:14 INFO mapred.MapTask: data buffer = 79691776/99614720
13/09/21 19:45:14 INFO mapred.MapTask: record buffer = 262144/327680
13/09/21 19:45:14 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: Map task executor complete.
13/09/21 19:45:14 WARN mapred.LocalJobRunner: job_local462595973_0001
java.lang.Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job.run(LocalJobRunner.java:354)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.serializer.SerializationFactory.getSerializer(SerializationFactory.java:73)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$MapOutputBuffer.<init>(MapTask.java:970)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$NewOutputCollector.<init>(MapTask.java:673)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:756)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:364)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job$MapTaskRunnable.run(LocalJobRunner.java:223)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:439)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

In a "too generic" way it always returns a null-pointer exception when tries to parse the file "023780-99999-2012". So I wrote a test for it (that you can see in the mapper tests "processRecordsFromSuspiciousFile") but it doesn't return errors.  I also checked through logs without any success.

Is it something related to wrong or missing local-mode parameters (number threads, heap-memory, etc)? or something wrong in the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hadoop has no idea out of the box how to serialize `Iterable`.  If you really intend to use `Iterable` as your output value class, you will also need to specify a serializer for `Iterable`.  Typical I/O types used with Hadoop are subclasses of `Writable`.

Update: I see now that you are intending to use `IntWritable` as your output value class.  Your problem is this driver line:

```
job.setOutputValueClass(Iterable.class)
```

should be

```
job.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class)
```

Comment: Thank you! Yes, I didn't see it and couldn't spot in logs and tests :)